# Database values with special characters, render with their HTML number, rather than with the data from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, razor

pretty new to angular here.

I have this information that comes from the database, and parsed by a Razor view HTML page in a controller:

Angular.js

```
$scope.init = {
   //this value comes from the controller as "Atención!" which is good.
   streetName: '@Model.StreetName'       
}

$scope.datas = angular.copy($scope.init);
console.log('Result: ', $scope.datas.streetName); 
//Result: Atenci&#243;n&33;
//Expected view: Atención!
```

Razor view HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="datas.streetName" name="StreetName">
```

Unfortunately, I can't change any structure of how this was made, I had tried with sanitize and no luck, $sce too, and no luck.

Is there a way to transform a string with HTML numbers ASCII codes, to normal special characters?

Thanks in advance,
Leo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Html.Raw()` and `Newtonsoft`?

```
$scope.init = {
   //this value comes from the controller as "Atención!" which is good.
   streetName: '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.StreetName))'       
}

$scope.datas = angular.copy($scope.init);
console.log('Result: ', $scope.datas.streetName);
```

Comment: Thanks man! That was what I needed, although it didn't work throwing an error that JsonConvert didn't exist in my context, I only used the @Html.Raw(Model.StreetName) and it worked perfectly. Leo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Html.Raw would be enough without Newtonsoft.

```
$scope.init = {
   //this value comes from the controller as "Atención!" which is good.
   streetName: '@Html.Raw(Model.StreetName)'
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Yes exactly, the JsonConvert.SerializeObject wasn't working in my solution for those views.